# Android GridView - update View based on position

Tags: android, gridview

I have a GridView, using a custom adapter (myAdapter extends BaseAdapter), where each item in the grid holds an ImageButton. getView() is working fine.

However, from elsewhere in my code, how can I update the image (setImageResource) for one particular item in the grid based on its position in the GridView?

So far, I've added this to my adapter class:

```
public void changeImage() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Image change");
        this.ImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.newImage);
}
```

And would like to write something like this: `mygridview.getItemIdAtPosition(20).changeImage();` (doesn't compile).

Answer (score 3):

If u want to update the image for one particular item in the grid, what u can do is...have an onClickListener for all the images in the grid.

Now when u will click on any of the image, get the position of the image and change ur background resource for that particular image.

Example:

While adding the image: *imageView.setOnClickListener(imageListener);*

And the listener will be something like dis:

```
private OnClickListener imageListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = v.getId();
            ImageView imgView = imageArray.get(id);
            imgView .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newImage);
    };
```

I hope u find it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

In case of Images in a GridView I did this and it works also:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View imgView, int position, long id) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imgView;
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.newImage);
        }
    });    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's also my last problem. Here my solution I use data Model and adapter for my RecyclerView
      **Firstly, register your new data to your model**

```
  DataModel detail = new DataModel(id, name, sat, image);
```

**after that, use set to replace old value with the new one**

```
  mData.set(index, detail);
```

**finally, refresh your adapter**

```
  if(adapter!=null)
  adapter.notifyItemChanged(index);
```