# Android Gridview update only one Element from outside the ImageAdapter

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, baseadapter

I have a gridview using an image adapter for the elements,
it's implemented like in this example:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Additionally I added a click listener for each item in the getView method, which sends the clicked position to the main class (outside of ImageAdapter) using a handler.

Now I want to update only the concerned imageView, but:

- I don't know how to get the imageView outside of the ImageAdapter class (send with the handler? It's not serializable - create a buffer in ImageAdapter and getter?)
- I'm not sure which method to use to change the image.

Currently I'm updating the whole grid each time:

```
((ImageAdapter)gridview.getAdapter()).setImages(imageIds);
gridview.invalidate();
```

ImageAdapter:

```
public void setImages(int[] images) {
mImages = images;
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: does it work like this? did u find better solution?

Comment: check this post, you may found your answer here
[How to update only one item in grid view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217491/android-gridview-update-view-based-on-position)

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently doing is somewhat correct.

As an optimization, you could use an `ArrayList<int>` as the images and create a method in your adapter class to modify the value of a given index using `ArrayList.set(int index, E element)`. Then calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` method should "theoretically" update the changed image view only :)

Comment: I don't think so. I just put a breakpoint, notifyDataSetChanged() refresh the whole set?