# Changing an image in a gridview when clicked, when certain other criteria are met

Tags: android, gridview

How to change an image in my specific gridview as I get the below error. I have followed similar examples elsewhere without success. ie I get "cannot change from integer to imageview" when trying the below, from
(see [Android GridView - update View based on position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217491/android-gridview-update-view-based-on-position)), i.e.:

```
int tempid = v.getId();
ImageView imgView = FruitToChooseFromImages.get(tempid);
imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blank);
```

I have also tried:

```
{   // remove viewable image / make blank
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v;
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
}
```

FULL CODE BELOW IF YOU NEED IT:

Main JAVA code:

```
public class game1mainscreen extends Activity {

private MyGridviewAdapter1 mAdapter; 
private GridView gridview;  

private ArrayList<Integer> FruitToChooseFromImages; 
private ArrayList<Integer> tempintarray;

int Totalfruit = 11; // starting from 0 of course (so an 11=12 fruit) this means there are 6 pairs of fruit to select
int fruitleft = 12;
int fruitstilltoadd = Totalfruit + 1;
int numberOfFruitToRemove = 6;   
int puthere = 0; 
int imagesSelectedThusFar = 0;
int Fruitleft = 0;


int firstfruitselected = R.drawable.blank; int firstfruitselpos;
int secondfruitselected = R.drawable.blank; int secondfruitselpos;

int removefirstimage = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gameonemenu);


    {        
        FruitToChooseFromImages = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        FruitToChooseFromImages.add(R.drawable.fruit0);
        .....etc....
        FruitToChooseFromImages.add(R.drawable.fruit11);

        }

    ...code removed which randomly sorts FruitToChooseFromImages (ie arraylist of images) into 6 duplicate pairs of images...


    // prepared arraylist is passed to the Adapter class  
    mAdapter = new MyGridviewAdapter1(this, FruitToChooseFromImages);  

    // Set custom adapter to gridview  
    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    gridview.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // DO THIS WHEN CLICKED
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
        { 
            int fruitselected = (int)FruitToChooseFromImages.get(position);     
            // start
            if (fruitselected == R.drawable.blank)
            {  
            // if blank/empty icon clicked on then DO NOTHING
            }

            else 
            { // firstly, say fruit name
                int soundtoplaynow = getrightsound(position, fruitselected);
                SoundManager.playSound(soundtoplaynow, 1);
              // next
                if (imagesSelectedThusFar == 0) 
                    {
                    imagesSelectedThusFar = 1;
                    firstfruitselected = fruitselected; firstfruitselpos = position;
                    //both switch fruit image to blank in the array and display blank at position clicked
                    FruitToChooseFromImages.set(position, R.drawable.blank);
                        {   // remove viewable image / make blank
                        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v;
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
                        }
                    }
                else // so two images have been selected! do they match?
                    {
                    imagesSelectedThusFar = 0; // has reached 2, so reset to zero
                    secondfruitselected = fruitselected; secondfruitselpos = position;
                    if (firstfruitselected == secondfruitselected)
                        {
                    GeneralSoundManager.playSound(0, 1);// play happy sound - change code to GeneralSoundManager

                        //switch fruit image to blank and display blank at position clicked **
                        FruitToChooseFromImages.set (position, R.drawable.blank);
                    {   // remove viewable image / make blank
                        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v;
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank);
                        }

                        int tempid = v.getId();
                        ImageView imgView = FruitToChooseFromImages.get(tempid);
                        imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blank);


                        fruitleft = (fruitleft - 2);
                        }

                    else
                        { // you selected the wrong fruit, sorry.
                    GeneralSoundManager.playSound(1, 1); 
                        FruitToChooseFromImages.set (firstfruitselpos, firstfruitselected);
                        // 
                        }   
                    }
            }    

             // end

            if (fruitleft == 0)
                {
                //end game - add code here
                }
        }
    });
}



// returns the sound to play depending on what image was clicked on
public int getrightsound(Integer position, Integer switchused) {
...etc.... 
    return soundtoplay;
}
```

}

My gridview adapter code:

```
public class MyGridviewAdapter1 extends BaseAdapter  
{  
private ArrayList<Integer> FruitToChooseFromImages;

private Activity activity;  

public MyGridviewAdapter1(Activity activity,ArrayList<Integer> FruitToChooseFromImages) 
{  
    super();  

    this.FruitToChooseFromImages = FruitToChooseFromImages;  
    this.activity = activity;  
}  


public int getCount() {  
    return FruitToChooseFromImages.size();  
}  


public Integer getItem(int position) {  
    return FruitToChooseFromImages.get(position);  
}  


public long getItemId(int position) {  
    return 0;  
}  

public static class ViewHolder  
{  
    public ImageView imgViewFlag;  

}  


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   
    ViewHolder view;  
    LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();  

    if(convertView==null)  
    {  
        view = new ViewHolder();  
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.gridview_row, null);  


        view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  

        convertView.setTag(view);  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
    }  


    view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(FruitToChooseFromImages.get(position));  

    return convertView;  
}  
}
```

My Main xml code - gameonemenu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/tree">
<GridView  

android:id="@+id/gridView1"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"     
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:numColumns="4"
android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My Grirdview_row xml code:

```
<ImageView  

    android:layout_height="64dp"  
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"  
    android:layout_width="64dp"  
    android:src="@drawable/blank"  
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">  
</ImageView>  


</RelativeLayout>
```

PS I used Grirdview_row xml which originally showed text but I don't need to display text only images but is this causing an issue?
PSS please keep your advice at the COMPLETE beginner level and include code if possible to match explanation. I cannot stress this enough. Thanks.

Comment: you have not specified  gridview's columnwidth

Comment: I have not tested your answer at this time, due to no early responses forcing me into the workaround of changing my code to refreshing the whole gridview. As you are the only one who has responded, kindly accept a "great comment" from me.